# trying to make a quick-stop feature in my pygame platformer

Tags: python

Basically I'm trying to make it so that when you hit the down key the players dx value goes to 0 so that they can basically stop on a dime thought this would be pretty simple but it is proving more difficult than expected when I try to call on it nothing happens

```
def Q_Stop(self):
    self.dx==0
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is a comparison operator , you want to use assign opertaor = :

```
def Q_Stop(self):
    self.dx = 0
```